# ¿Por que position: fixed no me fija el top menu?

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de que mi topmenu se quede estático aunque hagan scroll en la web o sea; quiero que mi menú se quede fijo en el header aunque hagan scroll.

Estoy utilizando `position: fixed` y no me esta funcionando.

Dejo los códigos para ver si pueden encontrar el error que no deja el menú fijo.

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(6, 5, 5, 0.8);
  background: #0D1014;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  color: azure;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #524d4d;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgb(87, 88, 89), inset 0 -1px 0px rgba(63, 59, 113, 0.2), 0 9px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 4px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 0 1px #040f1f;
  z-index: 600;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

body {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2 class="logo">xNova WoP</h2>

  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check" class="mostrar-menu">&#8801</label>

  <nav class="menu">
    <a href="#">Inicio</a>
    <a href="#">Servidores</a>
    <a href="#">Sobre WoP</a>
    <label for="check" class="esconder-menu">&#215</label>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Hola TéllezDM, te diría que con el código que has compartido, el error que describes no se puede reproducir. Utiliza la herramienta [edit] e intenta crear un [mcve].

Comment: Probablemente solo te falte un `top: 0` en el header